# In JIRA is there a way to create a nested table?

Tags: jira

The [JIRA documentation](https://jira.corp.yahoo.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=tables) does not mention a way to create a nested table something like

```
|outer-col1|outer-col2|
|col1 val1||inner-col1|inner-col2|
           |icol1 val1|icol2 val1|
           |icol1 val2|icol2 val2| 
|col1 val2||col2 val2|
```

(or) atleast something where I can span a multiple rows for a column value

i.e.

```
|outer-col1|outer-col2|outer-col-3
|col1 val1 |col2 val1a|col3 val1a|
           |col2 val1b|col3 val1b|
|col1 val2||col2 val2 |col3 val2 |
```

The only way I can span now is to have empty values in the column and have the reader assume that it represents the previous rows value for that column.

Answer (score 7):

Found a way around to make nested tables at below linked page
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Nested-table-in-wiki-markup-Confluence-4/qaq-p/18355

The solutions suggest many tags that can be used to achieve this. A simple one is `{panel}`  tag. Just wrap the Inner table inside two `{panel}` tags.
Below is a sample and its result

```
Sample
||Tabe1Column1||Table1Column2||
|item1.1|item1.2|
|item2.1|Sub table {panel}
||Table2Coumn1||Table2Column2||
|sub item1.1|sub item 1.2|
|sub item 2.1|sub item 2.2|{panel}|
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported in JIRA out of the box.

However, the [JEditor add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.jiraeditor.jeditor/server/overview) that is available on the marketplace does support this.

Since JEditor replaces JIRA's wiki editor it can have quite some impact on a JIRA instance, depending on how your users are used to work with mark-up. It can also affect other add-ons, so best to test properly before buying.